# What does `[4]` in `spark-submit --master local[4]` mean?

Tags: apache-spark

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications says

```
# Use spark-submit to run your application
$ YOUR_SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --class "SimpleApp" \
  --master local[4] \
  target/scala-2.12/simple-project_2.12-1.0.jar
```

What does `[4]` in `spark-submit --master local[4]` mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Run `local`-ly with `4` worker threads in the same JVM as the driver program.

Answer (score 1):

It represents the number of cores that will be assigned to the spark-submit process.

See the documentation here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

@shashank's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60768826/2129801) is correct, it's the number of cores that will be used by Spark when running in local mode.

For details you can check the code of [SparkContext.numDriverCores](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e37f66420bbb73da1a1a4d3ad02b175eedbb5052/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2691):

```scala
/**
  * The number of cores available to the driver to use for tasks such as I/O with Netty
  */
private[spark] def numDriverCores(master: String, conf: SparkConf): Int = {
  def convertToInt(threads: String): Int = {
    if (threads == "*") Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors() else threads.toInt
  }
  master match {
    case "local" => 1
    case SparkMasterRegex.LOCAL_N_REGEX(threads) => convertToInt(threads)
    case SparkMasterRegex.LOCAL_N_FAILURES_REGEX(threads, _) => convertToInt(threads)
    case "yarn" =>
      if (conf != null && conf.getOption("spark.submit.deployMode").contains("cluster")) {
        conf.getInt("spark.driver.cores", 0)
      } else {
        0
      }
    case _ => 0 // Either driver is not being used, or its core count will be interpolated later
  }
}
```

with

```scala
val LOCAL_N_REGEX = """local\[([0-9]+|\*)\]""".r
```

Answer (score 1):

local[4] represents the number of cores but its not a good practice to give a value there. it always better to give the core and executors outside the code